# Pandas: aggregate and join if different string

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

```
data = [['abc', 'bin_1', "bin_2"], ['abc', 'bin_1', "bin_1"]]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'bin1', 'bin2'])
```

And I want to merge the columns `bin1` and `bin2`.
As you see, there can be the same cell value in these two columns.
I want to combine the two columns by `|` if the values differ, otherwise just put a single unique value.

```
data["bin"] = data[['bin1', 'bin2']].agg(' | '.join, axis=1)
```

Unfortunately gives me:

```
name    bin1    bin2
abc bin_1   bin_2
abc bin_1   bin_1
```

if I want:

```
name    bin1    bin2    bin
abc bin_1   bin_2   bin_1 | bin_2
abc bin_1   bin_1   bin_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set`s if order is not important:

```
data["bin"] = data[['bin1', 'bin2']].agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)), axis=1)
print (data)
  name   bin1   bin2            bin
0  abc  bin_1  bin_2  bin_1 | bin_2
1  abc  bin_1  bin_1          bin_1
```

Or `dict.fromkeys` if ordering is important:

```
data["bin"] = data[['bin1', 'bin2']].agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(dict.fromkeys(x)), axis=1)
```

Comment: great, thank you! I was just wondering why it messes up the order :)